# What is a good knot to tie a short loop around a bracelet?

Tags: knots

I want to tie a hair band around a bracelet, so it's easy to store and remove. It's too short to put it around my wrist, so I tried a cow hitch, but I'd like something more compact/secure. Any ideas?

[image: loop around bracelet]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with the outdoors.

Comment: ok, is there a knots stackexchange site?

Comment: As you can see in the related bar to the right, we do have a wide range of knot questions, ie what type of knots are best for various outdoor activities, but your particular question just doesn't fit within scope...so, no, there isn't a knots Stack Exchange.

Comment: @nachocab Are you looking for a convenient way to store a hair band while backpacking? I'd think that would be on topic. :)

Comment: @ppl I like your spin :) yes!

Comment: @ppl Come on, this spin is making it somewhat [boat question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about) like!